# az: error: unrecognized arguments: --query loginServer

Tags: azure, docker, command-line-interface

I'm trying to deploy a test spring boot app using the Az Cli.
I've followed the steps to setup everything, but at the point of creating a docker registry:

```
export DOCKER_REGISTRY=$(az acr show --name acrTestProject3 \ --query loginServer --output tsv)
```

I'm getting this error

> "az: error: unrecognized arguments:  --query loginServer"

Comment: try updating az cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the script in the Linux system, there should not be the error here. And the `--query` is a global parameter. The Azure CLI was installed is the necessary condition. The result of my side shows here:

[image]

**Update:**

If you use the CLI command that I have shown in the answer, then there will not be the error. The character `\` means change the line. If you do not change the line, please delete the `\`.

[image]

Just run the CLI command like this:

```
export DOCKER_REGISTRY=$(az acr show --name acrTestProject3 --query loginServer --output tsv)
```

Comment: he already does that, and its not working. also, as the question mentions the error he is getting its clear the az binary is there

Comment: @4c74356b41 I explain in the update. You have to see the answer carefully.